# Linux tar with pattern match and removing leading paths

Tags: linux, tar

I'm trying to archive all the .log files located in the /var/log directory and on creation remove all leading paths on files.

I have found I can archive all the .log files easily with:

```
tar -cvf ~/backup.tar /var/log/*.log
```

unfortunately, after searching online the way to remove leading paths is to use `-C` to change directory for the command only now it doesn't recognize the `*.log` and thinks `*` is literal.

using:

```
tar -cvf ~/backup.tar -C /var/log *.log
```

I get an error saying cannot find file `*.log`.

I imagine my syntax must be off and I've tried some changes to the syntax with no avail.

Comment: `*` (and similar wildcards) are expanded by the shell before the command is invoked. Tar always thinks `*` is literal.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Okay that makes complete sense but there must be a way to do what I'm trying to achieve? I can do either one or the other but not both with my current knowledge.

Comment: Why not just change directory before running tar? `( cd /var/log && tar -cfv ~/backup.tar *.log )`

Comment: I'm guessing this is my only solution I had just hoped I could achieve all my commands from the home directory. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can run my command from your home directory. The parens make it run in a subshell, so the `cd` doesn't affect your original shell.

Answer (score -1):

Using **find** to pass files to **tar**:

```
find /var/log -name *.log -printf '%P\n' |\
  tar -C /var/log -czf backup.tar.gz -T -
```

- Find will look for *.log files and printf format the output to show just filenames.
- tar's '**-T -**' tells to read filenames from stdin